# How to integrate jQuery Static Gmap Zoom with visitors location?

Tags: jquery, maps

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial or explain how to integrate the jQuery Static Gmap Zoom - http://www.phpgeek.dk/staticgmapzoom with Google Maps.

Specifically I'm trying to display a map of the location of a visitor to my website with Google Maps API v3 and jQuery Static Gmap Zoom.

Thanks!

Jess

Comment: Do you have any code to post?

Answer (score 0):

this is how to find location. Change ip to your client ip. the result is in xml form.

```
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query.php?ip=127.0.0.1&timezone=false
```

Once u got lat & lng, this is javascript guide for pinpoint

```
var lat = 1.0001;
var lng = 0.1111;
var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                , scrollwheel: false
                , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                , zoom: 14
};
var yourNode = ...;
var canvas = new google.maps.Map(yourNode, mapOptions);
```

Comment: @rcravens - Stackoverflow prevents me from posting the code since there are multiple http addresses in there (apparently I don't have a good enough reputation yet to do this - silly rule guys!) So here is the link to what I have working (check the source) http://www.vpntelevision.com/geo/

Comment: Thanks for this! I will work on this tonight and report what I can come up with.

Comment: hmmm really have no idea but the website required registration, which is free right?. But if your client use HTML5, there's a location API u could use.